# ADC chip signalling - ADS4245

Tags: adc

I am designing a system with the ADS4245.
My requirement being a 14bit,dual channel I/P and a max of 125MSPS. I understand that going higher without the capabilty to program or select an output sampling rate would be a disaster. Hence-forth I went with the ADS4245.

With the requisite parameters are entered, the TI website recommends the ADS4245
But, the data sheet shows the output as LVDS.

How can then this serve my purpose please ?
I am attaching the image of that chip (and the LVDS info). Wouldnt LVDS be useless as in effect it is a 7bit differential output where as I am needing 14 bit output.

[image: ADC LVDS]

What is the difference between a normal 14bit ADC output and an LVDS output ?
I merely wanted to confirm that this would be of no use to me due to its LVDS capability.

Comment: It's 14 bit LVDS, at least the ADS4249 is.

Comment: So not a straighforward 14bit output. Thank you

Comment: It is 14 bit output, just LVDS so 28 pins.  To get the single ended version you would have to run them through LVDS to single ended converter.  The pinout is ideal for running into an FPGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AD4225 is 14 bits but only 7 output lines are provided with (say) D0 and D1 being multiplexed for the LSB line. Just because it is LVDS doesn't mean there is something "odd" about the outputs. Read page 13 of the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads4245.pdf).

The AD4245 is set for CMOS mode and you get all 14 bits (for both channels) outputted simultaneously. Read page 15.

Comment: Sorry I was looking at the EP version of the said chip (enhanced product). Apologies.