# length matching impact in ADC chips

Tags: layout

I am using the ADC4245-EP (enhanced product) adc chip. It has a normal version as well of it.There are 2 options of interfacing thiis ADC to an FPGA. They are CMOS or LVDS. The advantage of the LVDS being a better immunity to noise.  Now, the idea of LVDS is that we have signals that are complementary and hence the noise immunity is enhanced.  But, suppose I go for a simple CMOS voltage level, I must make some provisions for noise immunity.
The 1st thing that I will do is designing the bus with length matched tracks. This will help make the signals arrive at the FPGA at the same time (more or less) and hence make the design robust.

Is there any other aspects that I need to take into consideration when doing this layout ? Suppose if the tracks are not length matched, what is the impact ? How is the signal delayed or the extent of delay with increase in length (say even a few mils) . Can anyone direct me to any application note for such designs please ?

Comment: As the EP suffix is specific to TI, I assume you are using the ADS4245. It is impossible to answer your question without at least knowing what speed you intend to run it at.

Comment: Sorry its is the ADS4245EP. Indeed it is a TI and I am running it at 125MSPS. But my doubt was more generic on the length matching technique and any such for better layout for signal integrity.

Comment: Did your previous question (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189561/adc-chip-signalling-ads4245) get an answer you are happy with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your previous question, you are using a sampling rate of 125 MSps i.e. data is presented at the output every 8 ns. If the data were oscillating between 1 and 0 it represents a square wave of frequency of 62.5 MHz. For a reasonable rule of thumb I'd be interested in making sure that the 7th harmonic of that square wave (437.5 MHz) were passed to the FPGA reasonably unadulterated.

This means that the total track length should be no more than (here comes another rule of thumb) one-tenth the wavelength of 437.5 MHz. Wavelength of 437.5 MHz is 0.685m so max track length (without needing terminations) is about 70mm.

Now to your real question; can you see from the above rule of thumbs that providing you clock the data into the FPGA at somewhere near the middle of each symbol you are going to get a decent result. This means that track length variations of up to a few millimetres are not going to affect things very much at all. Clearly you do your best to equalize lengths but to no-better than (say) 5mm.

If you are using a much higher data rate then do the calculations based on above.

Comment: thank u.
What is the math for the 7th harmonic ?
Could you kindly point me to some document detailing that please ?

Comment: The 7th harmonic is just a rule of thumb that allows you to approximate a squarewave with limited bandwidth.